# Moving top two entries from master branch into an existing merged feature branch

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I know I have discussed this before but I always struggle to get it right!

Here is my log:

[image: Show Log]

This is what I want to do:

1. Move the 2 top entries into the **workbook-monthly-data-validation** branch.
2. Edit the message for that second from top entry. **Big** should be **Bug**.
3. The only entry at the `HEAD` should be *Completed the standardisation...*

So I want to end up with:

```
Completed ...
\
 \
  Introduced...
  Bug fix...
  Added new help button..
     down to 
  Added new window
 /
/
Standardised the placement...
```

What is the simplest way again to achieve this using **TortoiseGit?**

Thanks.

## Update

Somehow I managed to stuff it up a bit. It was all going OK following the first answer to a point. In the end I deleted the feature branch both local and remote and did a force push of the master. Things appeared right but I had lost some code changes. So I had to add a new entry again anyway to get it right:

[image: Log]

So I think I will have to leave it now. Technically those changes I have had to redo were part of the commits so I am confused.

I do have a copy of my original source folder with the feature branch still there so we could try again but I am unsure where I went wrong.

I know what was wrong. That message I wanted to end at the head was before other changes to the RC file. So it obliterated the changes made just before. I don't understand why it didn't raise any conflicts.

Comment: You can all commited changes back by using the reflog - even if no branch points to them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do it.

One would be to switch to the `workbook-monthly-data-validation` branch and reset (hard) it to the latest commit you want to have on this branch (switch to it first and then hard reset using the context menu).

Then select "Rebase onto" on the context menu for the commit you want to put the other two onto.

On the rebase dialog select edit for the commit you want to change the commit text and select skip on the merge commit.

Now you have all commits on the `workbook-monthly-data-validation` branch as you wanted them.

After that you have to modify master: Switch to it and hard reset it to the last commit before the feature branch. Then merge the feature branch again.

---

You can avoid such extensive rebasing sessions if you switch back to the just merged branch when you found a bug and commit your changes there. Then you can decide whether you reset your master branch (to the commit before your feature branch and merge again) or you just merge the feature branch again to master. This would look like the following szenario then:

```
| Bugfix (merge)
| \
|  | Introduced...
|  | Bug fix...
| Completed ... (merge)
| \|
|  | Added new help button..
|  |    down to 
|  | Added new window
| /
| Standardised the placement...
```

This way you still see which commits belong to your feature branch, but you don't have to do so many rebases/resets and force pushes.

Comment: Ok, that is good to know. In the end I managed to do it. Both of your answers helped me. I cherry picked the commits I needed back into the branch (and edited the text in the process). That got that right. But then I realised that these two commits superseded that **standardised** commit. It was no longer needed in the master branch. So eventually I got it all right with both of your help.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot vouch that this is the best solution but it works (which is the minimum requirement, right?). Time and other Answers will tell if there's a better/faster way.

- Switch/Checkout 'workbook' branch
- Ctrl-click-select the last 2 commits (the ones on 'master' you want to move to 'workbook'), right click, Cherry pick these commits

You'll get the Rebase UI.

- Change the one commit which message you want to change to "Edit", the other to "Pick" (default)
- Execute this.

In your example you have a prior commit meant to stay on 'master' ("Completed the standardisation...") This may lead to conflicts during this operation depending on the files affected by each commit. If so, just make sure you don't include changes from the commits you're NOT moving to 'workbook'.

Either way, Tortoise will also pause to let you edit the message of the commit you set as Edit. Just change the message in the text field and click Commit to continue.

At that point, the wanted commits will exist both in 'master' and 'workout'. Now to remove the ones from 'master'

- Switch/Checkout 'master'
- Right click on "Completed..." commit (first after merge), Reset 'master' to this, pick hard reset

Comment: Thanks for this. I encountered a problem. Please see the updated question.